# На сайт как-то инжектят php скрипты. Как выявить уязвимость?

Tags: php, linux, joomla, apache2, joomla3

У меня есть сайт на LAMP (Linux, Apache, PHP5.6, MySQL) на CMS Joomla! 3. Кто то постоянно инжектит скрипты на сайт которые редиректят пользователя на рекламные сайты.

Сами скрипты я постоянно удаляю но вопрос в том что бы выявить уязвимость. Возможно ли как то по названию файлов найти в логах Apache2 какой php скрипт загружает вредоносные скрипты.

Подскажите пожалуйста как выявить источник уязвимости. Спасибо.

Comment: включить логирование post параметров, а не только get. Посмотреть в итоге все запросы с подозрительными параметрами. Если сходу не видно, написать скрипты, разбирающие логи и дающие статистику по стандартным и особенно не стандартным значениям параметров запросов по каждому скрипту в отдельности. А вообще надо конечно посмотреть все скрипты на потенциально уязвимые операции, вроде eval. А так же на SQL-инъекции

Comment: права  записи в директории настройте корректно. у вас для записи от имени пользователя, под которым работает апач, должны быть доступны директории для логов, и для аплоада картинок так и документов. Все остальное должно быть только для чтения.

Comment: @teran хостер задал стандартные права. Какие права вы посоветуете?

Comment: Какая точная версия CMS?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Joomla 3.8.12

Comment: плагинов небось всяких установлено?

Comment: @teran только 1.

Comment: @Mike это будет в настройках apache логирования или php?

Comment: @IvanHanenko, когда появится очередной вредоносный скрипт, посмотрите его точную дату создания и в логах веб-сервера (apache) по тому же времени найдите запросы (скорее всего POST). По нему уже можно будет понять, что за уязвимость использует вредитель

Comment: @IvanHanenko Имею ввиду апач. Правда сейчас глянул, задача не совсем тривиальная. Это nginx "из коробки" умеет логировать post. А апач как то так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache

Answer (score 4):

> Сами скрипты я постоянно удаляю

Значит имя вредоноса вам известно. Анализируйте логи на предмет первого появления этого имени. Загрузить вредоносные скрипты можно несколькими способами.

1. У вас уязвимость в CMS. Анализируйте логи apache на предмет создания вредоносного файла. Изучайте новости безопасности по вашей CMS. Возможно уязвимость известна, просто вы еще не обновились.
2. Вредоносные файлы могут быть закачаны по ftp. Некоторые вирусы собирают сохраненные пароли или перехватывают пароли на ходу у популярных ftp-клиентов. Тогда надо проверить еще логи ftp. Проверить на вирусы компьютеры всех пользователей, имеющих доступ. Сменить пароли.
3. Уязвимость заранее заложена злоумышленником. Например вы установили CMS неизвестного разработчика или установили не из официального источника. И уязвимость была заложена "из коробки". Тут поможет только анализ кода.
4. Уязвимость не на сайте, а в браузере. Например установлено вредоносное расширение, которое добавляет вредоносный код в момент редактирования вами страниц сайта в CMS. Тут нужен анализ логов веб-сервера. Или журнала CMS, если в нем хранится добавленный текст.
5. Человеческий фактор. Может кто-то из сотрудников специально добавляет вредоносный код, зарабатывая по реферальной схеме. Тут -анализ логов веб-сервера, фтп-сервера, сравнение времени появления вредоносных файлов с временем работы пользователей

Comment: а может там и нет CMS То?

Comment: Я сортирую файлы по дате изменения и вижу что было закачено. Так я примерно выясняю что загрузили.

Comment: @IvanHanenko помните, что даты изменения легко подделываются

Comment: @IvanHanenko файлы не обязательно закачивать. Они могут быть созданы скриптом. Ищите в логах web-сервера запросы, которые явно не должны использоваться у вас. Например очень длинные запросы, в которых в одну строку записан целый скрипт

Answer (score 1):

Из личного опыта могу посоветовать сменить хостинг. Хостеры не всегда порядочные люди, да и не факт что взломали именно ваш сайт а не сервер.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/478730)

Comment: Ну если вы так уверены что хостинг не может являться причиной появления на сайте посторонних скриптов то удаляйте конечно.